# What does "MCS" means in intel's microcontroller MCS-48, MCS-51, and MCS-96?

Tags: microcontroller

Like the title said, I would like to under stand what does "MCS" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's Micro Computer Set, based on this datasheet:
https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/File:Intel_MCS-4_Data_Sheet.pdf

Comment: Intel Micro-Control System followed by the family number: 
Intel MCS-4 For 4004 Family
Intel MCS-8 For 8008 Family
Intel MCS-40 For 4040 Family
Intel MCS-80 For 8080 Family
Intel MCS-85 For 8085 Family
Intel MCS-48 For 8048 Micro Family
Intel MCS-51 For 8051 Family
Intel MCS-3000 For 3000 Family
Intel iPLDsProgrammable Logic Devices Family
Intel MCS-5000
Intel MCS-2900
Intel MCS-96 System For 8096 Family
Intel MCS-86 For 8086 Family
Intel iAPX 432 For iAPX 432 Family. These are the ones I remember.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

"Microcomputer System".  Not very interesting, but they have been using this since they got into the computer business.  I found an MCS-4 (4-bit) datasheet from 1971.

Comment: Thanks, I just Googled a lot, but I can't even find an explanation.